# CentOS 7.4: User Cannot Receive Multicast Packets

Tags: c, sockets, centos, multicast

#### Setup

- **Machine 1** (CentOS 7.4) has a process sending multicast UDP datagrams to an IPv6 site-local multicast group. The process is running as root.
- **Machine 2** (also CentOS 7.4) has a process whose UDP datagram socket joins the multicast group machine one is sending to, then continuously calls the (in this socket's case, blocking) `recv()` function.

Both applications are written in C.

#### Problem

When running as *root* on machine two, the datagrams **can** be received without issue.
When running as a *user* however, the datagrams are **not** received with the blocking `recv()` call.

The firewalld device has been stopped in both cases, and in both cases the socket creation is successful (no errors on the socket API calls... creation, joining, receive, etc.).

#### Question

What permissions, if any, might be preventing my process running as a user from receiving the same multicast packets that the process running as root can?

Comment: Just wondering - could it be an IPV6 problem.  Have you tried it with IPV4?

Comment: Have not tried with IPv4 because the applications rely on IPv6 features. Looking in Wireshark, as root I can see the ICMPv6 listener report messages, but as a normal user I can not.

Comment: That sounds like the packets is not leaving the source machine. Have you tried `iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT`?

Comment: `selinux` may be the pain in the ass, as always. Try to disable it, also on both machines.

Comment: @mnistic Wouldn't it be ip6tables? Also, I don't have iptables/ip6tables running (service for the former is disabled, the latter doesn't exist).

Comment: @Maxim-Mazurok SELinux was and is set to permissive.

Comment: @Squirrel, to be sure, it's better to disable it completely

Comment: also, which port are you using to create a socket?

Comment: @Squirrel did you try with a little `sudo`?

Comment: Given this description of the issue, I have a strong suspicion that with the way your program is written something doesn't let it join the multicast group when it's run without root privileges. Are you carefully checking return codes from every function you use to set up your multicast listener? For instance, as far as I recall `SO_BINDTODEVICE` requires root privileges. Sometimes, there are troubles with the interface index. Perhaps, you can show the MVP (minimal viable product) code for the listener?